# error creating an array of a tree recursively

Tags: php, recursion, tree

im trying to create an array of a tree recursivelly , but it is showing me an redundant error , the code is

```
private function printChildQuestions($parentid, $level=0) {
    $categorias = Categoria::model()->findAll("id_pai =".$parentid );

        foreach($categorias as $c){

            $space = str_repeat(' -&nbsp &nbsp ', $level);

            $flag=0;
            foreach($c->produtos as $p){

                $GLOBALS['children'][] = array("data" => $p->nome,"metadata" => array( "id" => $p->id ) );

                $flag=1;    
            }
            if($flag == 1){
                $GLOBALS['arvore'][] = array("data" => $c->nome,"metadata" => array( "id" => $c->id ) ,"children" => $GLOBALS['children'] );
            }

            $GLOBALS['arvore'][] = array("data" => $c->nome,"metadata" => array( "id" => $c->id ) );

            unset($GLOBALS['children']);
            $this->printChildQuestions($c->id,$level+1);
        }

}
```

the call of the function is         $this->printChildQuestions(0);

its returning me these values:

```
produtos       ---- ok 
  produto1     ---- ok 
produtos       ---- wrong line , repeated 1st line
subprodutos    ---- ok
  produto 2    ---- ok
subprodutos    ---- wrong line , repeated 4th line
subsubprodutos ---- ok
  produr 3     ---- ok
  produto 3.2  ---- ok
subsubprodutos ---- wrong line, repeated 7th line
produtos3.1    ---- ok
produto 2.2    ---- ok
produtos1.2    ---- ok
```

the correct would be

```
produtos       ---- ok 
  produto1     ---- ok 
subprodutos    ---- ok
  produto 2    ---- ok
subsubprodutos ---- ok
  produr 3     ---- ok
  produto 3.2  ---- ok
produtos3.1    ---- ok
produto 2.2    ---- ok
produtos1.2    ---- ok
```

Comment: And how should the values be?

Comment: Oh yes, that looks very clearly in a comment, please move it to your question?

Answer (score 0):

If in the first layer (level 0) you got repetitions the first line `$categorias = Categoria::model()->findAll("id_pai =".$parentid );` is to be blamed. For parentid = 0 it gives you repetition.

Comment: the first id is 1 , just the fist row has a id_pai = 0

Comment: Your code is straight forward. You call it with '$this->printChildQuestions(0);' So first argument from your method $parentid is 0. findAll takes id_pai  = parentid (which is 0 in your case). THen you have foreach. From what you pasted findAll for id=pai=0 returns repetition. It has nothing to do with your recurrence (which at the first glance look ok).